# JSON, replace quotes and slashes, but by what?

Tags: java, json

I have the ungrateful task to build a JSON String in Java, manually, without any framework, just a StringBuilder. I know this is bad, but it is only part of a prototype, I will do this better next time.

My question: How can I put the String -> `"Some text WITH quotes"` <- into a JSON object?

Of course, `{"key" : " "Some text WITH quotes" "}` is no valid json because of the unescaped quotes.

I think I have to use String.replace here, but by what can I replace the quotes? Same question for the slash "/". What is the proper replacement?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
"\"Some text WITH quotes\", slashes: /foo and backslashes \\foo"
```

translates to:

```
"Some text WITH quotes", slashes: /foo and backslashes \foo
```

You can use [`StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJavaScript(java.lang.String)) in [apache-commons](/questions/tagged/apache-commons) [Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) 2.6 or [`StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeEcmaScript(java.lang.String)) in 3.4 to do the hard-work of escaping for you.

Comment: Thanks to all, easier than I thought. Unfortunately, there is no escapeJavaScript in StringEscapeUtils, is it the same as escapeECMAScript? Maybe it was renamed/replaced.

Comment: @ceran: I mean `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript()` in Apache Commons Lang, the method name links to the JavaDoc.

Comment: I downloaded Commons Lang v3 and the method is not there. But StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript() does the same

Comment: @ceran: Oh, you are right, I linked to legacy 2.6 version. In 3.1 it was renamed to `escapeEcmaScript()`, updated my answer.

Comment: Link is dead.  Here it is: [StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html)

Comment: v3.5 contains `escapeJson()` method, but according to docs it was here since v3.2

Answer (score 2):

If you want to include a literal double quote in a JSON string, you must escape it by preceding it with a backslash `\`. So your JSON string would have to look like this:

```
{"key" : " \"Some text WITH quotes\" "}
```

See [json.org](http://www.json.org/) for the official JSON syntax.

The forward slash `/` is not a special character and does not need to be escaped. The backslash `\` needs to be escaped with itself: `\\`.

Beware that in Java source code the `\` is also the escape character and `"` also needs to be escaped, which means that if you use these as a literals in your source code you must escape them again.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("{\"key\" : \" \\\"Some text WITH quotes\\\" \"");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"\\\""+"Some text WITH quotes"+"\\\""
```

-> \"Some text WITH quotes\"

escape the escape char and escape a double quote in string

Answer (score 0):

With Prototype's string.evalJSON(), commons-lang's StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript method works fine, but with JQuery's jQuery.parseJSON(string), it doesn't work if the string value contains **apostrophes** which get escaped by the above mentioned method.

The JSON string shouldn't escape the **apostrophe** (== **single quote character**), strictly speaking.

So I use the StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(String) method which does the same as escapeJavaScript except for the single-quote character.

But it escapes the unicode characters into hex notation, which augments the length of the resulting script if the string contains many unicode characters.

Maybe we should use some JSON-dedicated libraries such as
**[net.sf.json.util.JSONUtils.quote(String)](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/util/JSONUtils.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29)**