# How to escape special characters from Callbackparameters in RequestContext?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I want to escape special characters which is appended in the RequestContext callback parameters.

The issue is clearly mentioned in http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=40444

Eg: 
On clicking the below button , doSomething is called.

```
<p:commandButton value="Save Event" style="float:right;margin-right:100px;" 
    actionListener="#{myBean.doSOmething}"                      
    oncomplete="if (args.facesMessagesAvailable){handleEditEventRequest(args);}
</p:commandButton>
```

In the server method, a parameter is passed via Request context to the client.

```
public void doSOmething() {
    String schEventsJson = "Hello & How are you?";
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addCallbackParam("eventList", schEventsJson);
}
```

The browser console shows
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'facesMessagesAvailable' of undefined

I think this occurred because of using **ampersand** in the callback parameter.
As the result the callback parameters are not available in the client side.

I tried enclosing args in encodeURIComponent, which was of no use.

Used the solution suggested by Hatem Aliman and also the one provided in  [JSON, replace quotes and slashes, but by what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359660/json-replace-quotes-and-slashes-but-by-what)
But the issue still exists.

Would like to know how to solve the same.
Any help is appreciated.

Using jsf 2.1 and primefaces 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `escapeEcmaScript()` which escapes the characters in a String using EcmaScript String rules..

`EcmaScript` is best known by the JavaScript and ActionScript dialects.

Example:

```
String schEventsJson = StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript("Hello & How are you?");
```

You can find it in the commons lang of apache

[`org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeEcmaScript(java.lang.String))

*Maven:*

```
<!-- apache commons -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I can see the problem already, and I usually use the above solution.

Comment: ok..:)..since my project is using commons-lang 2.6, i tried your solution using  StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript().. somehow this solution doesnot seem to to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange, I've never tried the escapeJavaScript method, but from the name it should work!

Comment: got the answer by using StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml

Comment: tested with apostrophe ' % # $%^&*(){}"':;,.\|~`<>?/ ..seems ok..but with period it displays an error in console "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ."