# unwrapping String within String

Tags: java, string, utf-8

I received a message from a queuing service, which I thought would be a UTF-8 encoded String.  It turned out to be a quoted and escaped String within a String.  That is, the first and last characters of the String itself are `"`, each newline is two characters `\n`, quotation marks (numerous because this is XML) are `\"`, and single UTF-8 characters in foreign languages are represented as six characters (e.g., `\uABCD`).  I know I can unwrap all this by rolling my own, but I thought there must be a combination of methods that can do this already.  What might that incantation be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Howto unescape a Java string literal in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/howto-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java)

Comment: Is it *actually* just JSON? If so, use a JSON parser.

Comment: @JonSkeet It's not JSON. Definitely XML content, escaped.

Comment: @JonSkeet: now that you mention it, what gknauth describes does look suspiciously like a json string.

Comment: @gknauth: But escaped as if it's a JSON string? What's producing it? How is it documented?

Comment: @JonSkeet It was produced by RabbitMQ, so I think you're on to something, that RabbitMQ used JSON to wrap it.  I usually use Jackson to deal with JSON, so I guess I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After feedback from @JonSkeet and @njzk2, I came up with this, which worked:

```
// gradle: 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;

String s = serviceThatSometimesReturnsQuotedStringWithinString();
String usable = null;
if (s.length() > 0 && s.charAt(0) == '"' && s.charAt(s.length()-1) == '"') {
  usable = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeEcmaScript(s.substring(1, s.length()-1));
} else {
  usable = s;
}
```

Comment: I should also credit this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359660/json-replace-quotes-and-slashes-but-by-what